# Trouble deleting entity with specific property set in Java GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the entities created like this:

```
public String addNewStockName(String newStock) throws DelistedException {
    Entity stock = new Entity("Stocks");
    stock.setProperty("Name", newStock);
    ds.put(stock);
    return "OK";
}
```

Trying delete the specific entity like this:

```
public String deleteStockName(String stockName){
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Stocks", stockName);
    ds.delete(key);
    return "OK";
}
```

And it does not delete the entity which has property 'stockName'. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Stocks` entity has a property named `"Name"`. That is not the same as the *key name*.

You have to perform a query to get the entities or entity keys matching the filter of `"Name=?"`.

Something like this:

```
public String deleteStockName(String stockName) {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Filter f = new FilterPredicate("Name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, stockName);
    Query q = new Query("Stocks").setFilter(f).setKeysOnly();

    List<Entity> results = ds.prepare(q)
            .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
    if (results.isEmpty())
        return "Not Found!";

    ds.delete(results.get(0).getKey());
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an entity that you can fetch by `stockName`, you need something like

```
public String addNewStockName(String stockName) throws DelistedException {
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("Stocks", stockName);
    Entity stock = new Entity(key);
    stock.setProperty("foo", "bar");
    ds.put(stock);
    return "OK";
}
```

You can then use your `deleteStockName()` method as is.  This of course assumes your key name is unique, but it also means you can always fetch the `Stock` by key, rather than query.